# При наведение на один компонента поменять стиль другого

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

Использую реакт, есть кастомный тэг. При наведении на блок, нужно поменять фон у другого блока, который лежит в этом же блоке. Первый файл:

```
<div className='card'>
    <First className='first' />  
        {widget()}
</div>
```

Файл с тэгом First:

```
const HeaderWidget = () => {
  return (
    <div>  
      <Second color='blue' className='second' />
    </div>
  );
};

const Second= ({color}) => {
   return (
       <div style={{backgroundColor: color} className='three'} >
            <button>Button</button>
       </div>
   );
}
```

css файл:

```
.card:hover . first .second .three{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Но этот способ не работает, цвет не меняется

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением !important

Comment: Как-то не особо. Сначала делать `style`, который главнее `class`-а, а потом еще сверху !important.

Mожно менять `background-color` на `button`, например.
Или какой-нибудь `background-image: linear-gradient...`